# Automatically reclassify grid into 5 classes using Processing

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, reclassify

I am using the graphical modeler of QGIS to rasterize a vector, and then reclassify it automatically into 5 values, without the intervention of the user.

I have reviewed the reclassify algorithm of SAGA but need user information to tabulate old value and new value.

How could you automatically calculate a grid in 5 values using the graphical modeler of QGIS?